# Computing the area of a convex hull in scipy

Tags: python, scipy, convex-hull

I wanted to compute the convex hull for a couple of points on a plane, using `scipy`.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull

points = np.array([[10, 10], [30, 10], [30, 20], [10, 20]])
hull = ConvexHull(points)
print(hull.vertices, hull.area)
```

It prints: `[0 1 2 3] 60.0`

So, the perimeter rather than area is returned (I checked another example, same behavior).
Is this a bug?
Python 3.7.4 (64-bit), scipy 1.3.1.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose `hull.area` refers to the perimeter in 1D and to the area in 2D. If you want the area delimited by a 1D hull or the volume delimited by a 2D hull, call `hull.volume` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The [definition of the Convex Hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) is based upon the perimeter, not the area:

> In mathematics, the convex hull or convex envelope or convex closure
>   of a set X of points in the Euclidean plane or in a Euclidean space
>   (or, more generally, in an affine space over the reals) is the
>   smallest convex set that contains X. For instance, when X is a bounded
>   subset of the plane, the convex hull may be visualized as the shape
>   enclosed by a rubber band stretched around X.

So this is an expected result. Although it seems to me that you have printed both the perimeter points (`[0 1 2 3]`) and the area (`60.0`)?

Comment: Yeah, I know what a convex hull is, only the terminology (area, volume) still sounds confusing to me. I printed the perimeter points as well, just to show they are computed correctly. Only 60.0 for my example is the distance around the square, i.e. what I would call the perimeter (according to a school or wikipedia definition). The area of my square is 10000.0, which is obtained after calling hull.volume. Thanks for your reply.